# How to generate series of dates in postgresql that are repeated every end of the month of another date

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, generate-series

I want to generate date data using postgresql function "**generate_series**" , however I have only advanced as far as the following:

```
SELECT
    ( DATE_TRUNC( 'month', ld ) + '1 month'::INTERVAL - '1day'::INTERVAL )::DATE AS pe_produc
FROM
    GENERATE_SERIES( TIMESTAMP'2022-01-31', TIMESTAMP'2022-3-31', INTERVAL'1 month' ) AS ld
```

The result of the previous query:

[image]

While the date structure I want to generate is as follows:

[image]

How should I modify my query to get the desired result?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should be generated by the function generate_series.

Comment: The same date mes_prod should be repeated for each different date in pe_prod through the generate_series function.

Answer (score -1):

With cte command I was able to fix it!

```
SELECT 
         a.pe_produc::date AS pe_produc
        ,b.mes_produc::date AS mes_produc
FROM 
    (SELECT
     generate_series('2022-01-31'::date
                     , '2022-03-31'::date
                     , interval  '1 month') AS pe_produc
     ,generate_series(1, (DATE_PART('month', '2022-03-31'::date) - DATE_PART('month', '2022-01-31'::date)+1)::int) AS b
     ) A 
    ,(SELECT generate_series('2022-01-31'::date
                       ,'2022-03-31'::date
                       , interval  '1 month') AS mes_produc 
     , generate_series(1, (DATE_PART('month', '2022-03-31'::date) - DATE_PART('month', '2022-01-31'::date)+1)::int) AS b
      ) B
```

Comment: That is not a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) statement. That is joined sub queries.